# onClick: jump/scroll to View/TextView

Tags: android, button, onclick, textview, visibility

i created a button, which changes the visibility of a textview.

Both are in a ScrollLayout and a vertical LinearLayout:

ScrollLayout

LinearLayout

...some other views...

Button

TextView

/ScrollLayout

/LinearLayout

On start of the activity the TextView visibility is set to "gone", so the Button is at the bottom of the screen.

My Problem now is that if i click on the Button and the TextView gets "visible" i have to scroll down to see the textview. I want it to scroll by itself to the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick I think,

```
scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
```